# What's the difference between "Y sont où ?" and "sont où ?" ?

Tags: grammaire, oral, registre-familier

From my understanding, “sont où ?” would mean “where are they?” so why is the “Y” at the start of the sentence needed? What does it convey?

Comment: "Sont où" or "Y sont où" alone does not mean anything. *Où sont-ils* would be common translation for "where are they". Or do you mean something else ?

Comment: I found it as "Y sont oú, ces amis?", I assumed it meant "where are they?, those friends", so it'd be understandable with just "Y sont oú"

Comment: I also found the following list http://lexiquefle.free.fr/banlieue/vocabulaire.pdf Last entry contains exactly this thing (informal meaning of y). Nice question:-)!

Comment: @Greg thats not true. This is a very common and familiar way to ask "where are they". At least in Quebec it is.

Comment: I had not thought indeed of the transcription of the "ils" with elision as "y". It is also common in spoken European French, but the written transcription as "y" is much less common and would be restricted to transcribing speech such as eg in dialogues in a comics, texting, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Y" stands for "Ils" in familiar spoken language, it should be "Ils sont où ?"

But the correct form is:

> Où sont-ils ?

Comment: “Où sont-ils ?” is the correct formal form, but it is not the only correct form. “Ils sont où ?” is correct informal spoken French.

Comment: @Gilles: C'est exactement ce que je dis.

Comment: Tu as écrit *but **the** correct form is* qui sous entend que c'est la seule forme correcte alors que *ils sont où ?* l'est aussi.

Answer (score 6):

The formal way to ask “Where are they?” in French is “Où sont-ils ?”. In informal spoken French, questions are often expressed by using the same word order as in an affirmative sentence (subject-verb-complements) and indicating that the sentence is a question solely through a rising tone at the end or, with a question word, just by the presence of the question word: “Ils sont où ?”. This is generally mentioned in grammar books.

In very informal spoken French, subject pronouns can be weakened. All the subject pronouns consist of a single syllable with a consonant and a vowel, and the weakened form is usually made by dropping the second sound. This is especially common with children, but it isn't limited to children. Many grammar books don't mention this and books won't use those forms unless they're conveying very informal speech on purpose.

- *je* → *j'* even when not followed by a vowel. When the verb begins with a [s] sound, [ʒs] turns into [ʃ].

  > *J'veux pas !*   (*Je ne veux pas.* — “I dun wanna!”)
  >   *Chais pas.*   (*Je ne sais pas.* — “I dunno.”)
- *tu* → t' (but rarely before a consonant)

  > T'es pas cap !   (*Tu n'est pas capable.* — lit. “you aren't able”, means “you don't dare”)
- *il(s)* → *y* before a consonant
  *ils* → *y-z-* before a vowel (the *liaison* stays)
  *elle(s)* → *è* or *y*, but this is rare
  *il/elle* → *l'* sometimes before a vowel
  *ça* → *a*, also rare

  > *L'est où ?*   (*Où est-il/elle ?* — “Where is he/she?” — rare)
  >   *Y sont où ?*   (*Où sont-ils ?* — “Where are they?”)
  >   *Y-z-ont rien vu.*   (*Ils n'ont rien vu.* — “They din't see nuffin'.”)
  >   *A veut pas marcher.*   (*Ça ne veut pas marcher* = *Ça ne marche pas* — “It's not workin'”)

  In “*il y a*” (and other tenses: *il y avait*, etc.), the word *il* disappears completely in this informal construction, and the *y* is pronounced as a semi-vowel [j]: “*y'a*” (pronounced as a single syllable [ja]), *y'avait*, etc.
- *nous* doesn't have a weakened form, but in informal speech it's replaced by *on* which is a single sound so can't be weakened any further.

  > *On a gagné.*   (*Nous avons gagné.* — “We won.”)
- *vous* → *z'* — unlike the other weakened forms I listed, which are fairly modern, this one is rather old-fashioned.

There are many variations on how to phrase questions in informal spoken French. The question word can stay at the beginning: “Où ils sont ?”, “Où y sont ?”. The medium-formality form “Où est-ce qu'ils sont ?” is rarely used in full, but can be shortened to the very informal “Où qu'y sont ?”. This form can in turn be reinforced to put the emphasis on the question: “Où qu'c'est qu'y sont ?”, “Où qu'est-c'qu'y sont ?”, “Où qu'est qu'c'est qu'y sont ?”…

Comment: Yes, the author was conveying very familiar speech and I had only come across the formal forms up until now, thanks a lot for this explanation, it'll help me in the future.

Comment: Existe-t-Il des livres dans lesquels on peut trouver de telles informales structures ?

Comment: Il y a aussi le très courant *où y sont ?* d'autre part,*è* pour *elle* est courant (ex: *è veut pas*) mais as-tu des exemples de *y* pour *elle(s)* ?

Comment: @jlliagre Je l'entend de temps en temps mais je n'ai pas tendance à l'utiliser. Comme tu peux t'y attendre, je n'ai pas d'exemple écrit sous la main.

Comment: @dimitris Le [Dictionnaire du français non conventionnel](http://www.languefrancaise.net/Argot/DFNC) peut-être ? Je ne sais pas s'il y a des détails grammaticaux ou seulement du vocabulaire.

Comment: Merci. Je crois que la tournure **y a des fautes de...** appartient ici (manque de il), non ?

Comment: @dimitris C'est un cas particulier : le *il* de « il y a » devient *y* et est fusionné avec le « vrai » *y* qui suit, d'où « y a ».

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre *è or y, but this is rare*. Est-ce que c'est *y* qui est rare ou les deux (la contraction de *elle* en général) ? Qu'est-ce que tu entends de temps en temps ? *è* ou *y* ? J'ai encore du mal à imaginer *y* utilisé pour *elle*.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai l'impression que la contraction de *elle* devant une consonne est rare (et même *il/elle* → *l'* devant une voyelle, c'est plus rare que la transformation *il* → *y*). Je pense que *y* est plus rare que *è*. Peut-être que *y* au féminin est particulièrement enfantin ?

Comment: Merci encore. Dernière question. La tournure **Faut que j'y aille** appartient dans la même categorie du français informal ? Il y a aille mais il manque il et c'est y paraît un peu bizarre.  Le correct est faut que je m'en aille, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: @dimitris *Il faut que j'y aille* = *Il faut que je m'en aille* sont soutenus. *Faut que j'y'aille* [fo.kœ.ʒjaj] = *Faut que j'men aille* (où dans les deux cas *qu'* à la place de *que*) sont des tournures orales informelles.

Comment: @Gilles Je vous remercie vivement:-)!

Answer (score 4):

Although it is hard to be sure without any context, "Y sont où?" is probably how the autor conveys a very informal spoken version of "Où sont-ils ?". It is very usual to lose the interrogative inversion in spoken language, turning it in "Ils sont où ?". If you tell this fast enough this is soon heard as "Y sont où ?".

"Sont où" on the other hand is hardly used alone although some might argue that speaking even faster you could indeed not hear the "y".

Note that the direction of the diacritic on the "u" in your question is also wrong, actually I’m quite sure ú is never used in French.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not native and I'm not familiar with this informal use of `Y`. Grammatically, neither **sont où** nor **y sont où** are correct.

With increasing level of formality the following are correct:

> Ils sont où ? Où ils sont ?
>
> Où est-ce qu'ils sont ?
>
> Où sont-ils ?

Googling a little, I encountered **y sont où, les/ces/...?** in various forums but I did not find any appearance of this structure in a grammar book or a grammar-oriented web-page.

On the contrary the affirmative phrase:

> Ils y sont.

meaning *they are there* is correct.

> Sont-ils à l'école/au théâtre ? Oui, ils y sont.

https://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/how-to-use-the-pronoun-y-in-french

Comment: *Y* in “Y sont où ?” is a weakening of “ils” in informal spoken French and is unrelated to the adverb.

Comment: I said it to my answer that I am not familiar with this use. I tried to answer based on my knowledge of the French Grammar. In any case this use of Y is incorrect. So I believe it is better to mention the correct uses of Y in this context. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: It is not correct in the sense of being mentioned in grammar books or being acceptable formal speech, but it is correct in the sense of being widely used by native speakers.

Comment: Nevertheless I still believe that this usage is incorrect and should not be acceptable. But this is my humble opinion. French language as it presented in Grammar books and classic authors is formidable. On the contrary informal French usage as the use of y here (I am not talking about argot) may cause headache if not embarrassement to non natifs...

Comment: Non-natives should be very cautious of *using* very informal language, but at some point they should *understand* it.

Comment: @dimitris What usage of *il* do you consider being unacceptable: writing it *y* or pronouncing it *y*?

Comment: @jlliagre All my comments have to do with writing Y instead of il. For pronouncing I think there is not a problem. I am not sure but I read somewhere that il may be pronounced y. My problem (being a not natif) arises mostly from the distance between standard French-the French that we learn in books FLE-and the familiar/informal French:-)!

Comment: Using a "phonetic" spelling when transcribing a spoken dialog is a common and accepted usage in literature. The requirement is for these sentences to be clearly distinguishable as spoken by quotes and/or a long dash, e.g. [*Y sont partis*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=zMwbTOTC2BEC&lpg=PT42&dq=%22y%20sont%20partis%22&hl=fr&pg=PT42#v=onepage&q=%22y%20sont%20partis%22&f=false)